# Wer, wie, was, wieso, weshalb, warum, all start with W in German. In English they don't, why?

Tags: etymology, orthography, germanic-languages

> Wer, wie, was, wieso, weshalb, warum. Wer nicht fragt bleibt dumm.

This is the theme song to the German Sesame Street, IIRC 
It roughly translates to:

> Who, how, what, why, why ,why. If you don't ask you stay stupid.

Anyhow the German question words all start with **W**. English seems to have fewer words for the same meaning compared to German and one of them is an exception and does not start with **W**. Why? English and German are both Germanic languages. So what happened here?

Also I did a [quick check](http://translate.google.com/#de/en/wieso,%20weshalb,%20warum) to be sure that **why** really has at least three counterparts in German. Did English have those and lost them?

> Wer --> Who
>  Wie --> how
>  Was --> what
>  Wieso --> why
>  Weshalb --> why
>   Warum --> why

Comment: *"I keep six honest serving men (they taught me all i knew); their names are What and Why and When And How And Where and Who."* – Rudyard Kipling

Comment: I’m not sure English really has fewer than German. Some other English ones include _whence, whither, which, wherefore, when, whom, whose_.

Comment: Just looking at *wieso*, *weshalb*, *warum*, it seems more plausible that German has lost an original word for *why* and had to construct substitutes.

Comment: @Carsten: in fact, German does seem to have lost an original word for *why*. [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/why) gives cognates of *why* in  Middle High German (*wiu*), Danish and Swedish (*hvi*) and Faroese and Icelandic (*hví*), but not modern German.

Comment: @PeterShor, the modern German cognate for that is simply _wie_. It’s just that this has come to mean ‘how’, rather than ‘why’ these days. (The Scandinavian words are also no longer in common use, except in Faroese. In normal speech, Danish and Swedish use _hvorfor_ and _varför_ ‘wherefor’, and Icelandic uses _af hverju_ ‘[because] of what’.)

Comment: Literally, "wieso" means "how so", and it is used in that form in English too, to mean "why".

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet "I’m not sure English really has fewer than German" - Not that it is precesely relevant to the OP's question, but German has actually a lot more question words than just those. An incomplete list (off the top of my head): wodurch, womit, wogegen, wobei, woran, worum, worauf, worunter, wovor, wonach, wovon, woher, wohin, wobei, worin, worüber, wohinter, wozu, wofür, inwiefern, inwieweit. These are all actually used colloquially (unlike for example whence and whither)

Comment: @TimSeguine, so does English. The ones you list are all _compounds_. They represent only three basic words: _wo_, _wor_, and _wie_. They’re like English _whereupon, whereafter, wherein, whereby, wherewith, whereto, wherefrom, wheretofore, whoever, whomever, whosoever, whomsoever_, etc. There are dozens of those English, too. I was talking about basic, unaugmented wh-words.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Then I would point out that under that criterion, German only has one word for "why", which is slightly more relevant to the OP's question.

Comment: @TimSeguine, absolutely correct. Note that when I wrote the first comment, the question did not specify “fewer words for the same meaning”, so I was just talking about how many distinct wh-words (that aren’t just transparent compounds with a preposition) each has. I don’t have an accurate number for either, but I doubt there’s that much of a difference.

Comment: Dutch is geographically in between German and English, and the Dutch translation would be "Wie, hoe, wat, hoezo, waardoor, waarom". "hoe" sounds like English "who", but shorter. So Dutch has made a similar wie/hoe/how transition, including wieso/hoezo/how so, and we don't have a simple cognate for "why" either.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: "I’m not sure English really has fewer than German. Some other English ones include whence, whither, which, wherefore, when, whom, whose." - I cannot quite follow that line of reasoning, as all of the words you list have matches in German. Hence, it's not like they'd compensate for the perceived lower number of question words in English pointed out in the question.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Sorry, but I don’t understand what you mean at all here. Who do you mean would not compensate for what perceived lower number? And where did I say anyone would compensate for anything? And what does that have to do with the fact that overall, the number of basic, non-compound _wh_-words in German and English probably don’t differ that much from each other?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: You stated English doesn't have fewer question words than German (which may well be the case). However, you attempt to prove that by citing more English question words in addition to those mentioned in the question, but each of those has an equivalent in German, as well, so they do not make up for the possibly lower number of English words for *why* pointed out in the question. I'm just trying to say that listing English question words that do *not* have a German equivalent (or several EN words that all translate to the same DE word) might be a better fit to prove the point.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, as I wrote in a previous comment (Mar 29 19:09), the question was framed differently when I wrote that. At the time, it just speculated that English had fewer _wh_-words than German, and I simply gave a few more to illustrate that there are quite a few more than the ones mentioned in the question. When the question was later edited, it became clear that DisplayName was talking specifically about the number of words for ‘why’, not the number of _wh_-words in total.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

English has—twice—gone through a phonetic change that has caused some upheaval in these pronouns.

#### The initial consonant

Originally, all of them (in Proto-Germanic) started with /ʍ/, that is, an unvoiced /w/. This is still found in some English dialects today; in Ireland and Scotland, for example, most people pronounce ‘wile (away the time)’ as [waɪl], but ‘while’ as [ʍaɪl]. This sound is a [voiceless labio-velar approximant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CA%8D), meaning it is pronounced with the lips round (labial) and with the back of the tongue moved up towards the the soft palate (velar).

#### Dissimilation

However, in the earliest stages of English, when this sound came before a rounded high or mid-high back vowel (i.e., [o] or [u]), which are also both labial and velar to a certain extent, it kind of became ‘too much’ for the speakers. Too much labialness, at least. So they dissimilated the sounds: /ʍo/ and /ʍu/ became /ho/ and /hu/.<sup>1</sup>

At that time, the word that is now ‘how’ was simply /ʍuː/, which of course turned into /huː/. The word that is now ‘who’ was /ʍaː/, and since that had a front vowel, it was not affected and remained as it was.

By the time they started writing down English, this change had already happened, so they wrote ‹hu› (‹hū›) and ‹hwa› (‹hwā›).

#### Vowel changes

Later on, English went through the [Great Vowel Shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift), which is basically a lot of the vowels moving about a bit. /uː/ regularly became [au] (like in German), and /aː/ usually became [oː]. Once this had happened, of course, the underlying, phonemic form /huː/ was pronounced [hau] or [haʊ], and there was no longer any clue whatsoever that it had once started with a /ʍ/.

The vowel shift also meant that earlier /ʍaː/ became /ʍoː/, written now ‹who› or ‹hwo›. This form then fell prey to the same dissimilation that had happened centuries earlier to /ʍuː/. /ʍoː/ became [hoː].

Later on, through a somewhat spurious and irregular change, the vowel in [hoː] became raised so that we end up with what we have today, which is pronounced [huː], but still written ‹who›.

And of course, in most dialects of Modern English, the distinction between voiced /w/ and unvoiced /ʍ/ has been lost, just like it was in German and Dutch several hundred years before.<sup>2</sup>

#### Several words for *why*

It is true that German has several words that can all be translated as ‘why’ (you mention *wieso*, *weshalb*, and *warum*). This doesn’t actually mean that English used to have these too, and just lost them—rather the opposite.

All Germanic languages have the possibility of creating compounds from interrogative pronouns by adding one of two things:

- Intensifiers and other pragmatic markers
- Preposition (or noun in the dative case, meaning ‘in the manner of X’)

English makes good use of the first (such words as *who(so)ever, where(soe)ver, what(so)ever, why(so)ever*), but more limited use of the second (*wherefore, whereto, whereby*, etc., all of which in addition belong to a somewhat more formal register).

German does it the other way around. I’m no great shakes at German, but apart from *wieso* I can’t actually think of any examples from the first category. In the second category, however, just about *any* preposition can be added to an interrogative stem.

*Wieso* is literally ‘why-so’, just like in English *whysoever*, except without *-ever*.

*Weshalb* contains *wes*, an old genitive form of *was* ‘what’ and *wer* ‘who’ (corresponding to English *whose*, which is the genitive of ‘who’ and ‘what’) + an old noun *Halbe* ‘half, side, direction’. So the original meaning was ‘in/on the direction/side/part of what?’.

*Warum* contains an old interrogative *wâr*, which has nowadays become *wo* ‘where’ + the preposition *um* ‘about, because of’. So the original meaning was ‘because of what’ (identical to ‘wherefore’, just with a different preposition).

By adding prepositions to the basic interrogative, German can create extremely specific wh-words; this is indeed not quite possible in English. For example, *wozwischen* ‘between what?’ is perfectly fine in German, but *wherebetween* (or *wheretwixt* if you want to be a bit Shakespearean) does not work in English.

But of original, shared, words for ‘why’ between German and English, there is only really one: *wie* in German (which has now come to mean ‘how’, rather than ‘why’, except in *wieso*) and *why* in English. The rest are later innovations in both German and English.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is a very common phenomenon in many languages. Compare how in Latin /kʷo/ and /kʷu/ (written as ‹quo› and ‹quu›, respectively) often become /ko/ and /ku/ if there’s another labial element nearby: *coquō* ‘I cook’, for example, represents and earlier **quoquō*.

<sup>2</sup> Similarly, the East Nordic languages (Danish, Swedish, and some dialects in Norway) have lost the distinction, but the West Nordic languages (Icelandic, Faroese, and some western dialects in Norway) have retained it. In Old Norse, /w/ became /v/, though, and the original /ʍ/ has now mostly become [kv] (from an earlier [hv] or [χv]) where it is retained.

Comment: Sounds good. Could you add some row of examples using "normal" letters to show the change in sound with how we would write the word(s) as it was spoken then the way we would write it now? That would make this a bit more accessible to me and others that are not fully initiated in phonetic language. Thx

Comment: @Display, that's rather a difficult task: the sound changes in question mean that the sequences of sound they affect do not exist, and cannot exist, in English phonotactics (and some of the vowels don't exist in English at all anymore). Given how badly English spelling matches pronunciation, it's practically impossible to represent something like [ʍoː] in regular English orthography.

Comment: Thanks, I reformatted and amended my question. Do you know of any lost substitutes for why? A thesaurus does not give any for english. For the German http://www.openthesaurus.de/synonyme/wieso all three counterparts to why are also synonyms.

Comment: *How come?* and *What for?* are substitutes for *why* which have not been lost: *"Why did you do that?" "How come you did that?" "What did you do that for?"* You shouldn't discount these just because they're two-word expressions.

Comment: _Wherefore_ is another one. The ‘extra’ German ones are all compounds, just like _wherefore_ and _what for_: _weshalb_ ‘on the side of what?’, _weswegen_ ‘through the means of what?’, _warum_ ‘because of what?’ (= ‘whereabout’, literally), etc. They are not simple, basic interrogatives that have been lost in English, but extensions of the simple words that simply have not been created in English.

Comment: Question words are a special class, and all of them in Germanic languages start with /w/, /hw/, or (in German) /v/. This is a result of Grimm's Law, which applies to Germanic languages and (among many other effects) turns the Proto-Indo-European labiodental stop *_kʷ_ into the Proto-Germanic labiodental fricative *_xʷ_. This is what got pronounced [ʍ]. All the PIE question works started with *_kʷ_, and this shows up in Latin with the pronouns that are spelled with QU most of the time: _quis, quid, quo, cuius, qui, quae, quod, quibus_, etc. They're cognate with English WH pronouns.

Comment: @John, easier (and more accurate) to say they started with /hw/ in Proto-Germanic, and with the plethora of outcomes that yields in various modern Germanic languages. Norwegian is particularly tricky, having a triple reflex, somewhat randomly distributed among dialects: [k], [kv], and [v]. Most Icelandic dialects have [kv], but a few minor ones have [χv] or even just [χ]. Standard Danish has [v], but in Jutland [w] or [ʍ] is more common. Dutch has mostly [ʋ]. And so on and so forth.

Comment: The comment of @RemcoGehrlich hints at a shift from:  wie/hoe/how in dutch as well. Thx. I'll re read trout it thoroughly again tomorrow. Am to tired to process this fully now.

Comment: German does in fact use intensifiers corresponding to *(so)ever*. It just doesn't write the result in a single word: *wer auch immer, warum auch immer, wo auch immer, wozu auch immer*.

Answer (score 1):

To your question regarding there being so many words for "why" in German:

There are actually 5 that I can think of in German, the two others are **weswegen** and **wozu**.

There are two things to point out: only "warum" is not a compound word. The rest are formed by combining more basic question words with prepositions. English has compound question words as well, so I am not sure it would be accurate to say that they have been "lost" in English. These more "exotic" question words just aren't as common in modern English.

The other thing to point out is that they all differ slightly in meaning. Here is an overview of what they mean if you translate a bit more literally.

- Warum: "why?"
- Wieso: "how so?"
- Weshalb: "wherefore?" (the question word analog of "therefore")
- Weswegen: "because of what?"
- Wozu: "for what purpose?"

In short, they all mean "why", but they aren't all necessarily interchangeable.

Comment: Somehow missed this previously. _Warum_ is a compound, too (_war_ = _wo_ + _um_), just a less transparent one in terms of Modern German.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Interesting. I must say it definitely is not transparent, considering that in modern German there is "worum" which has a completely different meaning.

Comment: I think it would be better to translate *wozu* as *what for*.

Answer (score 0):

English how is indeed an irregularity in the row of question words that all with the exception of how have the initial spelling  wh, but the pronunciation is either /w/ as in what, where, when or /h/ as in who, how.
It seems to be a bit difficult to explain the spelling and pronunciation of how as etymonline and the Oxford Dictionary of English Etymology refrain from explaining sufficiently this particularity.
It may be that at a certain time in the development of English the pronunciation of the words who and how became almost similar and to avoid this a process of differentiation began.

Comment: Could you please use italics or quotes when you're mentioning a word instead of using it? I'm having a very difficult time reading this answer.