# Why do Wh question words in English so consistently map to Q words in Latin?

Tags: etymology, latin

- Who, Quis
- What, Quid
- When, Quando
- Where, Quo
- How, Quomodo
- Why, Cur

There's one exception on each side, but otherwise this pattern is pretty consistent. Is there a linguistic or etymological reason for this?

Comment: Because they all come from the [Proto-Indo-European root *_kʷo-_](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/roots.aspx?type=Indo-European&root=k%CA%B7o-), the stem for relative and interrogative pronouns. Latin retains the original labiovelar stop, while English and other Germanic languages has had it changed by the processes called "Grimm's Law" into a labiovelar fricative /hw/, pronounced simply as /w/ by many speakers.

Comment: @JohnLawler and that's not an answer because ...?

Comment: I guess that's similar in other languages, those 5 words in German are: wer (who), was (what), wann (when), wie (how), warum (why), even without an exception :) +1 for the interesting question!

Comment: Also keep in mind that generally, the most common words in *any* language tend to be shortest, and also best-preserved over long time spans. Short words mean that there is only a limited number of sounds to pick from. Even unrelated languages might well form similar words through the linguistic equivalent of convergent evolution.

Comment: @KevinKeane: you are muddying the waters! This is definitely not a case of convergent evolution (even allowing that such a thing exists for languages).

Comment: Related, but concerned with later developments: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/160523/wer-wie-was-wieso-weshalb-warum-all-start-with-w-in-german-in-english-the

Comment: @bib feel free to write an answer yourself. comments like that are beyond annoying.

Comment: @sgroves I think John Lawler's comment is excellent (as do many others), and comments are not permanent on this site. It could disappear and that insight lost. My comment was meant to be an encouragement to transform his comment into an answer so we all can continue to benefit from it. I have no better answer, and merely copying John's comment into an answer posting of my own would not be right.

Comment: @bib I think the appropriate course of action if John doesn't make an answer would be to make a community wiki answer with his comment in it

Comment: @JohnLawler: Note that Proto-Indo-European probably didn't have relative pronouns.

Comment: Everything one needs to know is available in the answers here already. If it's short enough to fit in a comment, I think that's where it belongs.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Both sets of words come from a Proto-Indo-European root **kʷ(o)-* that probably marked an interrogative pronoun. In the Germanic languages, [Grimm's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grimm's_law) spirantized this **kʷ* into /xw/ or /hw/, which later merged with /w/ in many Germanic languages (Dutch *wat*, German *was*, Swedish *vad*, etc.), though not all: English has *what* (in some dialects still pronounced with and unvoiced /ʍ/), Icelandic has *hvað* /kvað ~ xvað/, and Norwegian is probably the silliest, having dialectal and lexical variation between /v ~ kv ~ k ~ Ø/ (the last only before back vowels).

In Latin, **kʷ* remained in most words as /kw/ (written ⟨qu⟩), so we have *quis*, *quod*, *quam*, etc. from this root. *Cūr* is from the same root, but before a high back vowel /u/ the labial element in /kw/ was usually lost in Latin, so early Latin *quōr* /kwoːr/ (which regularly became *quūr* /kwuːr/) yielded *cūr* /kuːr/. Even where Latin kept the labial element in /kw/, though, it usually (though not always) disappeared in the Romance languages, the daughter languages of Latin, leaving just a /k/ as in Spanish *que*, Italian *che*, French *quand*, etc.

In the other branches of Indo-European languages, the development was generally as follows:

**Greek:** in the largest dialect group, Ionic-Attic, PIE /kʷ/ (mostly) became /t/ before front vowels (τίς *tis* ‘who’, τί *ti* ‘what’) and /p/ elsewhere (ποῦ ‘where’). In some other dialects, it (at least sometimes) turned into /k/.

**Balto-Slavic:** In Slavic it generally resulted in /k/ before back vowels and č /tʃ/ before front vowels (Old Church Slavonic *čьto* ‘what’, *kъto* ‘who’); in Baltic generally /k/ everywhere (cf. Lithuanian *kas* ‘who, what’).

**Celtic:** It became /k/ in Goidelic (Old Irish *cia* ‘who’, *cid* ‘what’) and /p/ in Brythonic and Continental Celtic (Old Welsh *pwy* ‘who’, *pa* ‘what’).

**Indo-Iranian:** In Sanskrit it was mostly generalised to /k/ (कः *kaḥ* ‘who’, किम *kim* ‘what’), though it should have yielded /c/ before front vowels; in Iranian there was no such generalisation, and it generally became /k/ before back vowels and /tʃ/ before front vowels (Avestan *kō* ‘who’, *čim* ‘what’)

**Others:** In Hittite and Tocharian, it remained /kʷ/ (Tocharian *kus, kᵤse* /kʷse/ ‘who’, Hittite *kui-/kue-/kuu̯a-* /kʷi-, kʷe-, kʷa-/). In Armenian it seems to have been irregularly weakened to /h/, which was subsequently lost: the generalized stem հի- *hi-* became ի- *i-*, found in words like ինչկ *inč’* ‘what’.

[From StoneyB's comment:] Scots English employed /xw/ at least into the 16th century—and spelled it ‹quh›.  See [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/80308/24489).

Comment: And: in Slavic it generally resulted in _č_ /tʃ/ (or similar); in Baltic generally /k/; in Goidelic, /k/; in Brythonic and Continental Celtic /p/; in Sanskrit mostly generalised to /k/; in Iranian /k/ and /tʃ/ after back and front vowels respectively; in Hittite and Tocharian, it remained /kʷ/… and I'm too tired to think of more off the top of my head right now.

Comment: @StoneyB Icelandic still has that (well, /xv/, since /w/ was unrounded in Norse) in some dialects, though /kv/ is more common. Norwegian is probably the silliest, having dialectal and lexical variation between /v ~ kv ~ k ~ Ø/ (the last only before back vowels).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Norwegian sounds truly weird: my wife tells me that some of its dialects are actually *bringing back* inflections lost a century ago. Her linguistics professor practically fell on the floor when he heard that.

Comment: @StoneyB That's a bit artificial, though. It's a deliberate reintroduction of lost inflection, not a natural development—though I daresay in a generation’s time the result may well be the same.

Comment: @StoneyB That's great! People have reintroduced archaic features (with varying success) over the millennia. It makes for a nice conexion with the past. English does it too, e.g. the fairly recent rise in popularity of the present subjunctive in educated speech; the fairly recent acceptability of words like *albeit*, etc. I believe Dutch also reintroduced some case endings in the 19th century in writing, which later came to be pronounced again, for a time.

Comment: P.S. I have included the information from your comments in my question, pace vestrum.

Comment: Actually, the pronounced "h" is still naturally (without revival) widespread in the USA South as well as North of England and Scotland. This in turn respawns it in the wider language: a great many primary school children here (Australia) pronounce the "h" because they find it easier to learn the spelling of "wh-" pronouns: teachers often make a point of pronouncing it like this when teaching the spelling and I think they like the somewhat unwonted (to some people's ears) sound to play around with. There are also enough people around of Scottish / USA background that children hear it ....

Comment: .... naturally from some newsreaders and the like. I picked it up I think fairly naturally as a small child from my parents and grandparents (the latter of Scottish background).

Comment: @StoneyB Not really. Chaucer re-introduced great swathes of Anglo-Saxon words into his writings such that some of the commonest words today were revived by him ("lufu" became "love" and many others), living today after having spent a couple of centuries in stasis. Also, there can be a natural tendency to differentiate homophones to clarify meaning, so this could also explain a "revival" in some cases.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance great points, have some [Cool Hwip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0spEYBFLpLA).

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance O yah, /hw/ is standard in my own dialect (East Alabama). As for the 'reintroduction', I'm not talking about Norwegian lexicon, but Norwegian morphology--they're reviving abandoned inflectional endings! ... I think you're exaggerating Chaucer's "revivalism" -- he was extending the influence of a living language, not reviving a dead one. MED, for instance, has scores of instances of *love* (in various spellings!) from the 200 years after the last entries in the Anglo-Saxon Chronicle.

Comment: @Luaan Czech "jak" cognates with Panslavic "kak/kako", deriving ultimately from PIE *kʷ(o)-. The first part of "jak" comes from "jaký" (what/which), cognating with Lithuanian "jóks" ('any', see also "kóks", "tóks"), deriving from some other PIE root. "proč" got formed by contracting "pro co" ("for what"), akin in meaning to "pourquoi" or "wherefore".

Comment: The standard Indo-Europeanist theory distinguishes between *kʷ and *kw. The former cannot be split up into *k and *w. For this reason most of what you say in the first two paragraphs is wrong, unfortunately. Latin cūr is from Old Latin quōr. The ū/ō is not a vocalisation of the “w” part of *kʷ, but part of the IE root.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet's comment is also in part wrong. In Iranian *k and *kw become /k/ and /č/ before (not after) Indo-European back and front vowels respectively.

Comment: @fdb Yes, before of course, not after. That was a brain fart. I don't quite follow your first comment, though: the distinction between PIE _*kʷ_ and _*ku̯_ (and _*k̂u̯_) isn't really relevant here. The vacillation between /w(o)C/ and /uC/ mentioned here is _Latin_, not PIE (a more stringent vacillation of the same type existed in PIE, but that's not what's being talked about here); what matters is thus whether there's a /kw/ in Latin, not what it comes from.

Comment: @fdb Of course, this vacillation is not exactly what’s going on in _cūr_, since the /kw/ was never before a consonant; the /uː/ is the result of a regular raising of stressed, final /oːr/ to /uːr/, and the labiality of /kw/ is mostly lost before /u/ (and sometimes /o/). So while it may not be entirely _relevant_ to this word, I don’t think there’s anything _wrong_ about the the first two paragraphs as they are written.

Comment: @Luaan There is no such change from /kʷ/ to /kd/ in Czech, or anywhere else. The Slavic interrogatives in /kt ~ kd/ are shortened from Proto-Slavic /kъto/, which are from _*kʷos-_ plus an element _-to_, which is probably identical, or at least related, to the demonstrative pronoun _*tod_ ‘that’. Similarly, the ones meaning ‘what’ (_što_, _что_, _co_, etc.) are shortened from Proto-Slavic /čьto/, from _*kʷi[s/d]-_ plus the same _*-to_. PIE /kʷ/ becomes Proto-Slavic /k/ before back vowels and /tʃ/ (= _č_) before front vowels.

Comment: Wow, that is one hefty edit *not* made by the OP.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I know, it was quite a bit (and I’ve just added another one). Most of it was just moving around content that was already there, though (and removing a bit that was incorrect). Cerb, I hope you don’t mind (if you do, just roll back). :-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I call that bit of edit "rewriting", but if the OP doesn't object I suppose it's fine.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: On the contrary, I appreciate heavy edits from reliable sources!

Answer (score 15):

More specifically, you are seeing part of the sound change [*kʷ > hw [xʷ] in Grimm's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grimm's_law). Grimm's Law is a well known group of ancient sound shifts that affect *all* of the Germanic languages (not just English) and differentiate them from the Romance and Celtic languages that did not undergo the change. In fact, it can be argued that Grimm's Law *defines* the Germanic language family.

Grimm's law is also why English (Germanic) *foot* maps to French (Romance) *pied* and Latin *pedis*. The Proto-Italo-Celto-Germanic word underwent two consonant changes to become the Germanic form - the "p" morphed to "f" and the "d" morphed to "t".

Also, note that post-Grimm's law borrowings from Latin and French into English have resulted in pairings of related words, one of which displays Grimm's law (and is the native English word) and one of which does not. Examples are *hound* and *canine*, *hunt* and *capture*, *tooth* and *dental*, and *hundred* and *century*.

Comment: What about the vowel shift that you see in *pied* / *pedis* to *foot*?

Comment: @Cody Gray: New question = new question. Grimm’s law is only one of many sound laws (not all of them well understood) that describe the evolution from PIE to English on the one hand, and to Latin on the other hand.

Comment: BTW, the nominative form of the Latin word for _foot_ is _pes_, while _pedis_ is the genitive. (The French form derives from the Latin accusative, which is _pedem_.)

Comment: Also, note that post-Grimm's law borrowings from Latin and French into English have resulted in pairings of related words, one of which displays Grimm's law (and is the native English word) and one of which does not. Examples are *hound* and *canine*, *hunt* and *capture*, *tooth* and *dental*, and *hundred* and *century*.

Answer (score 5):

To add to [Cerberus's excellent answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/366665/54073) that all the words have the same Indic root, one can still see English language inscriptions in Scotland where the said *wh-* words are written *qu-*. I can only cite personal observation in several churches in Edinburgh and I don't know whether this practice arose from a natural orthography, from a Scottish wish to differentiate oneself from the English, or from a wish to reaffirm Scottish-French solidarity (several of the examples, if I recall correctly, were from the time of Mary Queen of Scots).

Comment: A few examples of the Scottish *qu*-words wouldn't go amiss here.

Comment: See [What was going on with "quha", "quilk" and the like in Scots and English?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/80308/8019).

Comment: I think you mean _Indo-European_, not Indic. The root is specifically not Indic, which is a separate subbranch of the Indo-European languages.

Comment: [An inscription at Scone Palace](http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/08/c7/9c/e4/scone-palace.jpg) has "qvohme" and "qm".  The 1695 _Act Anent The Mint_ has "quich".

Answer (score 1):

Great replies! I once took a course on Celtic languages and learned that there was a division between "p-Celtic" and "q-Celtic". I mention these terms here, as I haven't seen them in the posting above (they might not be official terms though).

A clear example: in English we have *father*, in Swedish we have *far*, in German we have *Fater* (I think), in French we have *père*, and in Latin we have *pater*.

I guess this is what is referred to as Grimm's Law above.

Comment: It's Vater, not Fater for German.

Comment: Pronounced that way though.

Comment: Grimm's Law refers specifically to the sound change that gives us "f" in Germanic languages like English, Swedish and German. The other types of sound changes in language groups like p-Celtic have different names, or sometimes no special names at all.

Comment: The terms _p-Celtic_ and _q-Celtic_ are not generally used by linguists anymore. It was once thought that those were the two main branches of Celtic, divided on the basis of what /kʷ/ became (/q = kʷ/ in q-Celtic, /p/ in p-Celtic). But there is wide consensus nowadays that this split is fairly incidental. The split between the Continental (Gaulish, Lepontic, Celtiberian, Galatian, etc.) and Insular (Irish, Scottish, Welsh, Cornish, Breton) Celtic languages was almost certainly the main ‘splitter’. The loss of /kʷ/ in all these languages happened later: first in Continental Celtic (generally →

Comment: → becoming /p/), then in the Brythonic branch of Insular Celtic (Welsh, Cornish, Breton—becoming /p/ as well), and finally in the Goidelic branch of Insular Celtic (Irish, Scottish—becoming /k/). This is similar to how, within the Italic branch of IE languages, Latin has retained /kʷ/, written ⟨qu⟩, while in Oscan and Umbrian it changed to /p/. You could also speak of ‘p-Italic’ and ‘q-Italic’ if you wanted; but no one does. The term only stuck for Celtic.

Comment: your knowledge in these matters astound me! Yes of course it is Vater. :) Like Lord Vader actually,  but that might be for another thread.