# Why all interrogative pronoun , 5W start with W?

Tags: etymology

The other day when I was looking at my grand daughter reading her English text book,I was suddenly asked by her why five interrogative pronouns - who, what, where, when, what begin with the letter, W. Is it mere coincidence? To my embarrassment, I’ve never fancied it. I checked the origin of five W in google to no avail. Can somebody teach her instead of me.

Comment: How did this happen?

Comment: This question asks about Latin, but covers the etymology of these words in English. Does this answer your question? [Why do Wh question words in English so consistently map to Q words in Latin?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/366664/why-do-wh-question-words-in-english-so-consistently-map-to-q-words-in-latin)

Comment: I reproduce below the comment I made in the duplicate question linked above: All the English _wh_- pronouns come from the [Proto-Indo-European root *kʷo-](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/roots.aspx?type=Indo-European&root=k%CA%B7o-), the stem for interrogative pronouns. Latin retains the original labiovelar stop (spelled with QU), while English and other Germanic languages have had it changed by the processes called ["Grimm's Law"](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/GrimmsLawCognates.pdf) into a labiovelar fricative /hw/, pronounced simply as /w/ by many speakers.